# Does tflite version of poseNet model support multiple pose estimation?

Tags: javascript, react-native, tensorflow, kotlin, tensorflow2.0

I was trying to implement poseNet model in tensorflow in react native with native module (bridging). The link I am referring is https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/posenet/android

In this I could only find the method for single pose estimation. Is there any other references for multiple pose estimation in tflite version of poseNet? Is it supported for tensorflow lite?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please post your code so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: It's the same repo in the link that am using. I've updated the link. I cloned it and integrated with my react native project. You can see in the file that, only singlePoseEstimation() is defined.

Answer (score 1):

I will start by saying, yes the multiperson pose estimation is supported by tflite, but for it you will have to use another tflite model, not the model proposed by tensorflow posenet, as this model only support one person detection.

i have used the flutter plugin code for multi person detection in images and videos in android (kotlin/java) with TFlite. The code is in my GitHub repository, as it is a big code, i can't post it here. The code can be found here (https://github.com/stevelaclasse/posenet/blob/main/app/src/main/java/cm/stevru/andropose/inference/DecodePose.java).
There you will see multiPoseEstimation() function.

I also experimented another approach for multipose estimation with the one person model. I have used a person detector model to detect all persons on the image, then i crop each detected person and create a new resized image with only this person, that i send to the one person poseEstimation model. It works pretty well on good images, but the cropped image with only a detected person has loose his quality so that the poseEstimation doesn't detect all poses on the image, and at the end just few poses are estimated on persons on the image. That is why i have chosen the multiPerson poseEstimation model.

You can also check this blog https://medium.com/flutter-community/posenet-for-ios-android-and-flutter-using-tensorflow-lite-836788a110c7 , to better understand the code.

The flutter plugin code for multiperson pose estimation can be found here: https://github.com/shaqian/flutter_tflite/tree/master/android .

I hope it will help you or someone.